Having one single issue with a xbox controller thats wired in 24.04
I'm having a lot of issues using a logic 3 pdp Xbox 1 wired controller. As kernel x pad is blacklisted and all game pad drivers for Xbox are blacklisted except xboxdrv however that one doesn't recognize my game pad. lsusb see's and says it's present in the USB listing and not having a red error. Can anyone help fix this issue? i know the usb's work as my 360 controller is seen in xboxdrv.
